# Does $\mathbb{Q}^n$ have larger cardinality than the set $\{(a_1,a_2,...) : a_i ∈ \mathbb{Z}\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Define $A = \{(a_1,a_2,...) : a_i ∈ \mathbb{Z}\ , \forall \ i\}$, which represents the set of integer sequences, and let $\mathbb{Q}^n$ represet the set of size $n$ tuples of the rationals

Both are uncountable, but does one of these sets have cardinality greater than the other set?

Comment: Hint: the countable union of countable sets is countable

Comment: Why do you say both are uncountable?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is countable as a finite Cartesian product of countable sets.

Comment: Did you mean $a_2$ where you typed $a_22$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{Q}^n$ is countable and $A$ is uncountable.